# Modifying a page from JQM dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

What I'd like to achieve is a page that has a couple of buttons inside a div. When the user presses one of these buttons a dialog opens, asking follow up questions. After this the user is returned to the same page but the div with the buttons is hidden.

What I've tried is the following, inside a JQM page i have div called buttons which contains the buttons(logically). this opens the dialog and also calls a function which saves to local storage which button was pressed. Then the dialog opens which actually sends the data to the server.

For some reason the div is never hidden when I return from the dialog. I even tried to save a variable to the sessionStorage and hide the div on pageload, but seems that the page load event does not fire when returning from the dialog. Any suggestions or am I missing something basic?

```
<div class="ui-grid-b" id="buttons">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><a  href="#Popup" data-rel="dialog" onclick="savePushedButton('green')"></a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><a  href="#Popup" data-rel="dialog" onclick="savePushedButton('yellow')"></a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><a  href="#Popup" data-rel="dialog" onclick="savePushedButton('red')"></a></div>
</div><!-- /grid-b -->

// the dialog: 
<div data-role="dialog" id="Popup" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
        <form>
            <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
              <h3>Heading</h3>
              <textarea name="comments" id="popuptextarea"></textarea>
              <button type="submit" data-theme="b" onClick="save()">Selv&auml;</button>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

I have two javascript functions which try to save the data and also hide the div,

```
function savePushedButton(color) {
    //save which button was pressed to local storage
    $('#buttons').hide();
    console.log("asd");

}
function save() {
//send data to server
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**onclick** is your problem (**onchange** also), do not use it with jQuery Mobile. jQuery Mobile has already started transition to the dialog, before **onclick** has been triggered. You will need to manually bind a click event to the button and hide buttons before transition to dialog can occur.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/uhsfs/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#test-button', function(){     
        $('#buttons').hide();
        savePushedButton($(this).attr('data-color'));
    });
});

function savePushedButton(color) {
    console.log(color);
    $.mobile.changePage('#Popup', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'}); 
}
```